# Placeholder in constructor chaining?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validationattribute

I was going through a material and the code for the custom validation logic is as follows:-

```cs
public class MaxAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
   public MaxAttribute(int maxWords) : base("{0} has too many words.")
   {
       _maxWords = maxWords;
   }
   public override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
   {
       if(value != null)
       {
         var valueAsString = value.ToString();
         if(valueAsString.Split(' ').Length > _maxWords)
         {
           var errorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName);
           return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);
         }
       }
       return ValidationResult.Success;
   }
       private readonly int _maxWords;
}
```

It says,

> The placeholder exists the call to the inherited *FormatErrorMessage* method, will automatically format the string using the display name of the property."

I am not able to contemplate just how the flow will be like?
All I know is when I type this say,

```
   [MaxWords(10)]
   public string Name{get;set}
```

The **MaxWordsAttribute(int maxWords)** constructor will be called and that will call the base constructor **:base({0}...)**
Just when and how is call to FormatErrorMessage will fill in the placeholder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The place to look is that call to `FormatErrorMessage`: that's the place where the error message is constructed. So [let's take a look](https://source.dot.net/#System.ComponentModel.Annotations/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/ValidationAttribute.cs,1e30b068cc75c330):

> ```
> public virtual string FormatErrorMessage(string name) =>
>     string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, ErrorMessageString, name);
> ```

That `ErrorMessageString` is the string you passed to the base constructor (in a [slightly](https://source.dot.net/#System.ComponentModel.Annotations/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/ValidationAttribute.cs,12be35703420378f) [roundabout](https://source.dot.net/#System.ComponentModel.Annotations/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/ValidationAttribute.cs,63) [way](https://source.dot.net/#System.ComponentModel.Annotations/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/ValidationAttribute.cs,52)).